# How to find numbers with comma in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

Query number like below data doesn't get any result, but space after commas it can find.

**Sample data:**

```
{
  "data":"34543,2525,5674,879"
}
```

**Query:**

```
"query": {
  "query_string" : {
    "query" : "(data:2525)"
   }
}
```

**Settings:**

```
"analysis":{  
   "filter":{  
      "my_ascii_folding":{  
         "type":"asciifolding",
         "preserve_original":"true"
      }
   },
   "analyzer":{  
      "default":{  
         "filter":[  
            "lowercase",
            "my_ascii_folding"
         ],
         "char_filter":[  
            "html_strip"
         ],
         "tokenizer":"standard"
      }
   }
}
```

For example querying `2525` in `"34543, 2525, 5674, 879"` found, but with `"34543,2525,5674,879"` doesn't find.

Comment: How are your fields analyzed?

Comment: I have added, tokenizer is standard

Answer (score 1):

Without any more information it looks like you're probably using the standard tokenizer. You can show how your tokens are analyzed by using

```
GET users/_analyze
{
  "text": "34543, 2525, 5674, 879"
}
```

or

```
GET users/_analyze
{
  "text": "34543,2525,5674,879"
}
```

If you're using the standard tokenizer then 34543,2525,5674,879 is only one token in your inverted index. When you search for 2525 it won't match that token. On the other hand, 3453, 2525, 5674, 879 is tokenized into four tokens without commas. 2525 matches the second token.

If you want to solve this problem you'll need to use a different tokenizer that *always* tokenizes on a comma rather than just when it's at the beginning or end of a token [Indexing a comma-separated value field in Elastic Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31143136/indexing-a-comma-separated-value-field-in-elastic-search).

Comment: I have added tokenizer information. How can I tokenize on a comma?

Comment: I added a link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31143136/indexing-a-comma-separated-value-field-in-elastic-search. That should answer your question.