# ELASTICSEARCH: Comma separated list giving inconsistent results with standard analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch

Running a basic query against my elastic search database is giving inconsistent results.

I can match against the DB querying by ID directly

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "id": {
                  "value": "84e042ce-74e3-4c51-a1d9-db2f1c3d57ef"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
    }
}
```

This returns one record as expected (2 fields shown)

```
"id": "84e042ce-74e3-4c51-a1d9-db2f1c3d57ef",
"usersNotified": "e721a8d9-8001-4003-9af9-1c7397fd7079,fc18bbc4-f7f1-4151-bf88-390597da9510,061c9195-cb97-4777-8577-a8e555b95c7f,8e4e7641-b135-46e5-b9b4-c42393450108,601785e7-1c18-43b4-924e-cf52a15e3204,ec132f25-3d1d-41d8-ab16-e60a53ee9483"
```

When I add a match_phrase to the query looking for a Guid that is present in the "usersNotified" field it comes back empty.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "id": {
                  "value": "84e042ce-74e3-4c51-a1d9-db2f1c3d57ef"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "match_phrase": {
                "usersNotified": {
                  "query": "601785e7-1c18-43b4-924e-cf52a15e3204"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
    }
}

{
    "took": 4,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 20,
        "successful": 20,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 0,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}
```

The exact same query for a different record (and a shorter list of usersNotified) does successfully return a match

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "id": {
                  "value": "d48e6ccc-f343-4840-af29-317fef829da1"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "match_phrase": {
                "usersNotified": {
                  "query": "601785e7-1c18-43b4-924e-cf52a15e3204"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
    }
}
```

As shown:

```
"id": "d48e6ccc-f343-4840-af29-317fef829da1",
"usersNotified": "e721a8d9-8001-4003-9af9-1c7397fd7079,fdc40427-9db0-44d8-8ce3-45c90489dc19,061c9195-cb97-4777-8577-a8e555b95c7f,601785e7-1c18-43b4-924e-cf52a15e3204,ec132f25-3d1d-41d8-ab16-e60a53ee9483"
```

So I don't understand why the same query works in one scenario but no tthe other. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you provide the sample data?

Comment: I've included the relevant fields above. ("id" and "usersNotified") after each of the queries. Unfortunately I can't post more than that as it contains sensitive information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I have this solved but I haven't been able to test it fully (and won't be able to for a couple of sprints ... so I thought I'd update with what I have).

I think the reason I wasn't matching on the UIDs in my field was because the standard analyzer defined for that field was analyzing using a language based algorithm and treating the dashes in the GUID as a hyphen and removing them from consideration.

I still don't understand why it would match some times and not the other, but following this [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31145497/1188043) I was able to rescan a small subset and get the desired results.

Essentially I created a custom analyzer that tokenized the field as a comma separated list. I then replaced

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "id": {
              "value": "d48e6ccc-f343-4840-af29-317fef829da1"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "usersNotified": {
              "query": "601785e7-1c18-43b4-924e-cf52a15e3204"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

with

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "id": {
              "value": "d48e6ccc-f343-4840-af29-317fef829da1"
            }
          }
        },
        {
           "term": {
               "userssNotified": {
                   "value": "601785e7-1c18-43b4-924e-cf52a15e3204"
               }
           }
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

And it worked. I'll get a chance later to try with the full data set (a full rescan is required) to see that it works.